# Value Type Vs Reference Type - Object Class C#

Tags: c#, object, reference

if Value Types and Reference Type are from Object Type which is a reference type, then how value type is value type and reference type is reference when they all come from refernce type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, it is a cheat ;-p

Any `struct` (i.e. anything inherited from `ValueType`) is treated with value-type semantics. But there is a **boxing conversion** to `object` as necessary; meaning that if you cast a `struct` to an `object`, it will create a special object (on the managed heap) containing the data (as a clone) from your value*.

The boxed version is a reference-type. You can unbox this (by casting) back to the `struct` version, which reverses this (copies the clones data from the object on the heap into your local value).

---

*=unless it is an empty `Nullable<T>`, which boxes to `null`; likewise, `null` unboxes to an empty `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: Can you explain me or point to a link on how the magic(cheating) is happening? i.e. Struct is value type while object reference type

Comment: @skjagini - simply, the compiler and runtime can spot easily that something is derived from `ValueType`, and treat it differently... Beyond that? ECMA335

Comment: +1 Although languages like C# pretend that a boxed structure is a value type, within the guts of the CLR every managed value type has a corresponding class type which encapsulates a field of the corresponding value type, and wraps all members to those of that field.  Even if C# language spec calls such a thing a value type, it will behave as a reference type.