# Object.ReferenceEquals never hit

Tags: c#

Can anyone tell me why the following condition does not hit?

```
List<DateTime> timestamps = new List<DateTime>();
timestamps.Add(DateTime.Parse("8/5/2011 4:34:43 AM"));
timestamps.Add(DateTime.Parse("8/5/2011 4:35:43 AM"));
foreach(DateTime x in timestamps)
{
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, timestamps.First()))
    {
        // Never hit
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you'd expect two values of a **value** type to be **reference** equal?

Comment: My intention was to skip the first element in the list but didn't realize DateTime was a value type. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Well hold on a minute. If your intention was to *skip the first element*, then why did you write this code at all? Just write `foreach(DateTime x in timestamps.Skip(1))` and be done with it. *After you fix the equality comparison you will be skipping every element in the list that is equal to the first element, not just skipping the first element.*

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, but by the time I wrote this I just wanna try it out in a different way and thought DateTime was a reference object, and thus used Object.ReferenceEquals instead of == or Equals().

Comment: While it would have worked with reference types (assuming that there could either be no aliases of the same object, or that skipping it would be desired), but would still have been less efficient than the more obvious approaches of `Skip(1)` or indexing starting with index 1.

Comment: Even this returns false: `int i=1;object.ReferenceEquals(i, i);`Here's an article that explains better why `Object.ReferenceEquals` always returns `false` on value types like structs: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2008/03/19/object-referenceequals-valuevar-valuevar-will-always-return-false.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because DateTime is a value type, immutable and so the references will not be equal even though the values are.

Are you meaning to do something like this? Value comparison:

```
if (DateTime.Compare(x, timestamps.First()) == 0)
{
    // Never hit
    Console.WriteLine("hello");
}
```

Comment: So if you had a mutable value type, the references would be equal?

Comment: The question was rhetorical. You mentioned immutability. The point is that even for mutable value types (those evil things), reference equality would not be met.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Right, I mentioned immutability because you always get a copy of the value rather than a shallow, reference copy.

Comment: That's not the way we typically think of immutability in relation to types, but OK. Unrelated to the answer, can you explain why you think even reference types wouldn't evaluate to true in the given snippet, as per your comment? You would agree that for a list of `class Foo`, the first foo in the foreach would be referentially equal to foos.First(), correct?

Comment: Immutability does actually play a role here: The collection is of value types and when the extension method First is called, it returns a copy of a new value object. That's the reason that even though you seemingly compare an array element to itself, you're not because the returned value is a new copy. Reference values would actually evaluate to true on the reference comparison on the first item comparison, but not subsequently.

Comment: Immutability is about whether or not a value can change, not about how it is copied, what list.First() is doing, etc. The fact that the value is being copied here says nothing about whether `DateTime` itself is immutable or not. You *could* make a mutable value type, stuff a handful of them into a list, pass that list through the logic in the question, and experience the same failure *because* of everything else you say in your answer. Would you agree?

Comment: Yes, I agree. The logic in the OP initially confused one of my comments, which I've since removed. Reference types would actually evaluate to true due to the logic but the fact that the condition in the original snippet is never satisfied is because of the immutable nature of the data type being evaluated.

Comment: @PaulSasik not in the slightest. Strings are immutable, and can be reference equals. Two mutable value types, or the same one boxed two times, cannot be reference equals. Immutability is completely orthogonal to reference identity.

Answer (score 6):

Value types are passed and compared *by value*. That's why they're called "value types".

Reference types are passed and compared *by reference*. That's why they're called "reference types".

DateTime is a *value type*.

Therefore you are attempting to compare two values *by reference*. That's not going to work. It will always be false.

Can you explain why you'd expect something different?

Comment: Eric the most likely explanation for someone expecting that sample to return true is that person not knowing the types they are working with are value types.

Comment: Interestingly, does `Object.ReferenceEquals` on two value types then compare the references to the boxes for equality? Is there a useful reason to do that?

Comment: @JamesDunne it would, so `object x = default(DateTime); object y = x; return ReferenceEquals(x, y);` returns true. Not much of a useful reason to do that most of the time though.

Comment: @JamesDunne: Does it compare references of the boxes? Yes. Is that useful? No.

Comment: If the list was an `ArrayList`, and the foreach used `object` as the type, than this would have actually worked. Obviously this makes perfect sense, but it is quite surprising.

Answer (score 3):

I think that a number of the other answers miss something.

In the case of `object.ReferenceEquals(object,object)` any value-types are "boxed" to objects and it is these (new) objects which are passed. Consider the following:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime d2 = d1;
object ob1 = (object)d1; // boxed!
object ob2 = ob1;

// false - the values in d1 and d2 are BOXED to (new) different objects
object.ReferenceEquals(d1, d2);
// false - same as above, although I am not sure sure if a
//         VM implementation could re-use a BOXED object
object.ReferenceEquals(d1, d1);
// true - naturally - BOXED only once at "boxed!" (same object!)
object.ReferenceEquals(ob1, ob2);
```

Happy coding.

---

Related: Marc's answer in [Value Type Vs Reference Type - Object Class C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205444/value-type-vs-reference-type-object-class-c-sharp) where he talks about a **boxing conversion**.

Answer (score 1):

They have the same value, but they aren't the same reference.

Take a look at the MSDN entry for [`Object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx)

Furthermore, even if you had been comparing the same object, you would still not hit it by comparing the references, because [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) is a structure, that is, it is value type. [`Value Types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), by definition, copy the contained value, not the reference to the object (like [`Reference Types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) do).

Comment: But what is passed to a method that takes an `object` as a parameter? (Say, `object.ReferenceEquals(object,object)`) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Objects get copied first inside ReferenceEquals because they are of value type, so references are never equal.